# Passing object from silverlight client to wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I am trying to create a WCF service that will loop through a list of my client classes and add them to a database using Entity Framework. The client object looks like so;

```
public class ClientScreenControl
    {        
        public int ControlId { get; set; }
        public string ControlName { get; set; }
        public string ControlTextContent { get; set; }
        public string ControlDescription { get; set; }
        public char ColumnNumber { get; set; }
        public char RowNumber { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeManditory { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeHidden { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeReadOnly { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the Save method in the WCF service;

```
public void SaveToDatabase(List<ClientScreenControl> listOfControls)
        {
            SilverlightScreenDesignerEntities ent = new SilverlightScreenDesignerEntities();

            foreach (var item in listOfControls)
            {
                ent.ScreenControls.Add(item);
            }
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
```

How do i pass a `List<ClientScreenControl>` to a WCF service that cant reference the silverlight application? Is there another way to generate this save method?

Comment: How does the service method even compile, if the ClientScreenControl class is not known? The solution is to put the class into the service, it will be created on the client automatically by the reference wizard.

Comment: Are you saying that "Add Service Reference" isn't working for the Silverlight project?

Comment: @nvoigt it doesnt compile at the min. Oh right so if i create a class within the Service Library it will reflect on the client side?

Comment: @LLoyd yes, the service interface and all types directly used by it will be generated on the client side, too. Please note that they are different classes, only fields will be transfered, not methods.

Comment: Just tried that @nvoigt and worked first time, thanks for the help